# Is there a way to save a single image and to prevent user put more than an image using dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dropzone.js

I'm try to upload image in database, i'm using drobzone.js 
that's my controller code

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Show(int? id)
{
    string mime;
    byte[] bytes = LoadImage(id.Value, out mime);
    return File(bytes, mime);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    SuccessModel viewModel = new SuccessModel();
    if (Request.Files.Count == 1)
    {
        var name = Request.Files[0].FileName;
        var size = Request.Files[0].ContentLength;
        var type = Request.Files[0].ContentType;
        viewModel.Success = HandleUpload(Request.Files[0].InputStream, name, size, type);
    }
    return Json(viewModel);
}

private bool HandleUpload(Stream fileStream, string name, int size, string type)
{
    bool handled = false;
    try
    {
        byte[] documentBytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
        fileStream.Read(documentBytes, 0, documentBytes.Length);
        Pictures databaseDocument = new Pictures
        {
            ProfilePicture=documentBytes,
            FName=name,
            Size=size,
            Type=type
        };
        using(var contxt=new EnglisCenterEntities())
        {
            contxt.Pictures.Add(databaseDocument);
            handled = (contxt.SaveChanges() > 0);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception )
    {
        // Oops, something went wrong, handle the exception
    }
    return handled;
}

private byte[] LoadImage(int id, out string type)
{
    byte[] fileBytes = null;
    string fileType = null;
    using(var contxt=new EnglisCenterEntities())
    {
        var databaseDocument = contxt.Pictures.FirstOrDefault(doc => doc.IdPicture == id);
        if (databaseDocument != null)
        {
            fileBytes = databaseDocument.ProfilePicture;
            fileType = databaseDocument.Type;
        }

    }
    type = fileType;
    return fileBytes;
}
```

and this is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#preview").fadeOut(15);
    $("#refreshButton").click(function () {
        var imageToLoad = $("#imageId").val();
        if (imageToLoad.length > 0) {
            $("#preview").attr("src", "/Document/Show/" + imageToLoad);
            $("#preview").fadeIn();

        }
    });
});
```

and this is my view

```
<form action="/Document/Upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
<input type="text" name="imageId" id="imageId" />
<button type="button" id="refreshButton">Update Image</button>
<img src="/" style="display: none" id="preview" />
```

and it's working with multi images but i want to save single image and prevent the user put more than one image. Is there a way to save a single image and to prevent user put more than an image using dropzone.js?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is needed to limit maxFiles, see http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration-options and http://jsfiddle.net/P2dTF/2/ for example:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = true;
Dropzone.options.my-awesome-dropzone = {
    maxFiles: 1
};

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    SuccessModel viewModel = new SuccessModel();
    if (file != null)
    {
        viewModel.Success = HandleUpload(file);
    }
    return Json(viewModel);
}
```

Param name of `file` is important, dropzone binds single upload to param file (and multiple to a param array of files). Don't see why you need a `fileStream` though, `fileStream` is needed when you want to return a range of bytes for example with a Request Header (audio) for partial download, `HttpPostedFileBase` does the job in your case.

```
private bool HandleUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    bool handled = false;
    try
    {
        byte[] documentBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];

        Pictures databaseDocument = new Pictures
        {
            ProfilePicture=documentBytes,
            FName=file.FileName,
            Size=file.ContentLength,
            Type=file.ContentType
        };
        using(var contxt=new EnglisCenterEntities())
        {
            contxt.Pictures.Add(databaseDocument);
            handled = (contxt.SaveChanges() > 0);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception )
    {
        // Oops, something went wrong, handle the exception
    }
    return handled;
}
```